# Bash and Root Privilege Issues

Tags: bash, sh, root

So, I'm working through a security lab in an Ubuntu virtual machine at the moment and I've run across an issue. The instructions can be a bit vague or unclear at times. As of now, I wrote a small C program that runs ls.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    system("lsBAK -la");
    return 0;
}
```

I then made a backup of /bin/ls under the name lsBAK and deleted the original. I made a link to my compiled program under the name ls, so that when I type, ls, this program will run instead. It ultimately allows me to run ls on folders I shouldn't have permission to run it on since it has root access. The question that ultimately prompted me to do this was written as follows: "Can you let this Set-UID program (owned by root) run your code instead of /bin/ls? If you can, is your code running with the root privilege? Describe and explain your observations."

That's all good. Now I'm supposed to do the same with bin/sh or /bin/bash.

The instructions literally say: "Now, change /bin/sh so it points back to /bin/bash, and repeat the above attack"

I've tried a lot of variations on the same program. What I don't seem to get is how to run bash. If I type sh into the terminal, I immediately go into that shell. If I type bash, nothing happens, even though sh is a link pointing to bash. It seems like it may actually be opening a shell, but it looks exactly the same, whereas when I run sh I get a clearly different shell to play with that shows sh-4.3# instead of the usual root@.... How is it possible that running sh gives me a different result than running bash, when sh is just a link to bash? What am I missing?

I mean, when I recreate sh, I'm simply running: ln -s bash sh

I've tried things like ./bash, bash, etc. What I currently have is a mostly identical program where I'm doing the following system call:

```
system("bash");
```

I removed sh and created a link to my new program, shUID, under the name sh. So, what I imagine should happen is that when I run sh, it runs my program shUID, which does the system call. Whenever I run sh, the terminal simply locks up until I hit ctrl+C.

So I'm obviously looking for whatever I'm missing here. I assume I did that previous question, involving ls, correctly but I can't seem to figure out what's going on here. Help is appreciated.

Edit: I've moved on in the lab for now and have discovered that system() actually calls /bin/sh, so my issue here seems to be that if I'm replacing it and relying on a system call, there's a problem here. I'm currently unsure on what to do with this information, but it gives me some direction. I'd still appreciate help, but I'll play with this new information shortly.

Comment: If you are running `bash`, then run `bash` again, it *will* look the same because both instances used the same initialization to configure, for instance, the prompt. Run `echo $$`, then run `bash`, and run `echo $$` again: you should see different output because the previous and current instance of `bash` are separate processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that will help you see what is happening with some Socratic questions following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    printf("uid %d gid %d euid %d egid %d\n", getuid(), getgid(),
        geteuid(), getegid());

    printf("argc %d\n", argc);
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);

    if (argc >= 2 && (argv[1][0] != '/')) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing initial slash\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (execv(argv[1], argv+1)) {
        perror("execve");
        return 1;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

What is a UID, what is an EUID? Why do I check for an absolute pathname for the file to run? Why do I use `execv` instead of `system`? What does the `-p` option for `bash` do?

Why is there the statement:

```
if (running_setuid && privileged_mode == 0)
    disable_priv_mode ();
```

in the [startup code of bash around line 496](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c#n496)? Finally, is this code subject to the same attack as the code in your exercise?

I've not shown the compilation steps for this code because if you don't know what it does, you should not be building it.

Answer (score 1):

In fact /bin/sh is not just a symlink to bash on most systems. Observe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    /* if we were using bash this would not fail */
    system("type history");
    return 0;
}
```

Even though this snippet reports the environment variable `$SHELL` as `bash` it is indeed not the shell we are using: (Read: this may cause confusion )

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    system("echo $SHELL");
    return 0;
}
```

On Debian, FreeBSD, NetBSD and Ubuntu this will hold true. In fact only a small number of OS are using `bash` as the default system shell and many of them are reverting back to an almquist shell derivative for POSIX sh.

You may find the following command helpful if you want to use `bash` from `system()`:

```
bash -c "ls"
```

Or for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    system("bash -c 'type history'");
    return 0;
}
```